# Eclipse Build Javadoc package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running an Ant build in Eclipse and javadoc is reporting a package that does not exist.  This does not stop the build from completing but I would like to resolve it.    This is the javadoc section of the build-impl.xml file in Eclipse.  If I mouseover the javac.classpath in the  section I can see a list of the jar files.  The package that Javadocs is complaining about, the jar file is in the list.   If I go to the declaration for javac.classpath it takes me to a property file for a netbeans project.  this project started as netbeans and was later imported to Eclipse.  The javadocs problem is relatively new, it started last week but the project is a few years old.  I have gone through that file and everywhere I can find the javac.classpath I have added the name of the jar file.  I am not sure where else to look.  This doesn't prevent the project from being built, but it is annoying.  The error is:

```
[javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
 [javadoc] /Users/foo/Projects/SwitchLogCollector/src/dc/sanswitch/Main.java:7: error: package org.apache.commons.cli does not exist
 [javadoc] import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;



            -->
<target depends="init" if="have.sources" name="-javadoc-build">
    <mkdir dir="${dist.javadoc.dir}"/>
    <condition else="" property="javadoc.endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg" value="-J${endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg}">
        <and>
            <isset property="endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg"/>
            <not>
                <equals arg1="${endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg}" arg2=""/>
            </not>
        </and>
    </condition>
    <condition else="" property="bug5101868workaround" value="*.java">
        <matches pattern="1\.[56](\..*)?" string="${java.version}"/>
    </condition>
    <javadoc additionalparam="-J-Dfile.encoding=${file.encoding} ${javadoc.additionalparam}" author="${javadoc.author}" charset="UTF-8" destdir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" docencoding="UTF-8" encoding="${javadoc.encoding.used}" failonerror="true" noindex="${javadoc.noindex}" nonavbar="${javadoc.nonavbar}" notree="${javadoc.notree}" private="${javadoc.private}" source="${javac.source}" splitindex="${javadoc.splitindex}" use="${javadoc.use}" useexternalfile="true" version="${javadoc.version}" windowtitle="${javadoc.windowtitle}">
        <classpath>
            <path path="${javac.classpath}"/>
        </classpath>
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${bug5101868workaround},${excludes}" includes="${includes}">
            <filename name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${build.generated.sources.dir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <arg line="${javadoc.endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg}"/>
    </javadoc>
    <copy todir="${dist.javadoc.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${excludes}" includes="${includes}">
            <filename name="**/doc-files/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${build.generated.sources.dir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
            <include name="**/doc-files/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target depends="init,-javadoc-build" if="netbeans.home" name="-javadoc-browse" unless="no.javadoc.preview">
    <nbbrowse file="${dist.javadoc.dir}/index.html"/>
</target>
<target depends="init,-javadoc-build,-javadoc-browse" description="Build Javadoc." name="javadoc"/>
<!--
```